# Pipe Character (|) not accepted as part of regular expression

Tags: php, regex

regular expression php doesn't accept `(" | ' ) ,`
here's my `$pattern = '/(img|src)=("|')[^"'>]+/i';`

How can I escape `("|')` problem.

Comment: escape special (+.[] etc.) chars with a backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes for the quote ' inside the pattern. Your pattern is defined between single quotes so you've to escape the single quotes part of the pattern. 
Try this:

```
$pattern = '/(img|src)=("|\')[^"\'>]+/i';
```

Comment: Thank you, Bgi, it really works for me. thank you so much for your help/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

> $pattern = '/(img|src)=("\|')[^"'>]+/i';